# How to determine table name within a Rails 3 model class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to get table name in a model method. I [found](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-table_name) there should be method table_name but when I try to call it I get NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `table_name'. It is obviously not there:

```
 pp methods.grep(/^ta.*/)
["table_name_prefix?",
 "table_name_suffix?",
 "taint",
 "taguri",
 "taguri=",
 "tainted?",
 "table_name_prefix",
 "table_name_suffix",
 "tap"]
```

How to get a "real" table name (no lowecase - pluralize tricks)?

Thanks

Comment: It's a class method, not an instance method. Try `Model.table_name`.

Comment: But I need that information in the model's instance method. How to get it?

Comment: self.class.table_name of course :-)

Comment: Yeah, `self.class.table_name` is possible too...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> But I need that information in the
>   model's instance method. How to get
>   it?

You can simply do this in your instance method:

```
class Model
  def instance_method
    puts Model.table_name
  end
end
```

Comment: I see but unfortunately my instance method is in different module which is included. It has some general functionality, therefore I need to use self. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Found it.

It's a class method. Its not so obvious from the Rails 3 documentation.

```
self.class.table_name
```

Comment: Btw how to do the reverse process? Find class name for table name?

Comment: table_name.classify.constantize

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a class method of the class you want the table name for, try:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.class_method
    puts self.table_name
  end
end
```

If you try using

```
self.class.table_name
```

you'll run into a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'table_name' for Class:Class`