# How to find a model class from its table name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This question is reverse of this question: [How to determine table name within a Rails 3 model class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139640/how-to-determine-table-name-within-a-rails-3-model-class) .

My intention is to look at Rails project database and try to figure out all possible model classes the project is related to. I have few clues, such as to get table name list from AR connection, etc. But down to table_name -> model class mapping. I got no idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

The method called to do this in Rails is #classify (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify). If you can use Ruby (or Rails itself), just do the following:

```
"table_name".classify
```

or to actually get the class name:

```
"table_name".classify.constantize
```

Comment: How do you handle namespaces? Ie. `'admin_users'` -> `Admin::User`

Comment: @JamesKlein `'admin/users'.classify`

Comment: `group_budget_line_items` could be nested, or it could be plain.  So, unless one comes up with a clever scanner of the `app/models` directory, it's not generally possible to know the class name for that table if has been nested. 

For example: the path could be: `group/budget_line_items`, with a class of `Group::BudgetLineItems`, or `group/budget/line_items` with a class of `Group::Budget::LineItems`, or, even `group/budget/line/items` with a class of `Group::Budget::Line::Items`.

Answer (score 20):

How about:

```
def index_by_table_name
  @index_by_table_name ||= ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.reject(&:abstract_class).index_by(&:table_name)
end

klass = index_by_table_name[table_name]
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer because the one by @Austin works on strings and not actual models. What if a model has a custom table_name? This solution has it covered.

Answer (score 8):

The better way, is to go the other way around, load all models and extract their table names.

Rails 6.x / Zeitwerk

```rb
# load all clases
Zeitwerk::Loader.eager_load_all

# get all named classes extending ApplicationRecord
all_models = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c < ApplicationRecord}.select(&:name)

# build the index
model_by_table_name = all_models.index_by(&:table_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the ruby API http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize

The     `constantize` method will convert your string to a constant

Because your table name like job_applications, you'll need convert it to "JobApplication", look for `humanize, titleize` or `classify` method that is supported also.